# Inserting space in result in perl

Tags: regex, perl

I have a number like `600000`. I want to insert space after every 2 digit. How can I do it? The result should be `60 00 00`.

Comment: what do you want for 1234567?

Answer (score 7):

If `12345` should become `12 34 5`, I recommend

```
s/..(?!\z)\K/ /sg
```

The `(?!\z)` ensures that you don't add a trailing space.

---

If 12345 should become `1 23 45`, I recommend

```
s/(?!^)(?=(?:..)+(?!.))/ /sg
```

`(?!^)` ensures you don't add a leading space.

This isn't very efficient. It might be more efficient to `reverse` the input, use the first solution, then `reverse` the output.

Answer (score 5):

Compared a few different methods of doing this. I assumed that you didn't want to modify the original string, otherwise the 100% regex version might have done better.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;

use Benchmark ();

my $x = "1234567890";

Benchmark::cmpthese(1_000_000, {
    unpack   => sub { join(" ", unpack("(A2)*", $x)) },
    regex    => sub { (my $y = $x) =~ s/..(?!\z)\K/ /sg; $y },
    regex514 => sub { $x =~ s/..(?!\z)\K/ /sgr },
    join     => sub { join(" ", $x =~ /..?/sg) },
    });
```

Seems that using unpack() is the fastest

```
             Rate     join    regex regex514   unpack
join     221828/s       --     -18%     -26%     -42%
regex    271665/s      22%       --     -10%     -29%
regex514 300933/s      36%      11%       --     -22%
unpack   383877/s      73%      41%      28%       --
```

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
$number = '600000';
$number =~ s/(\d{2})(?!$)/$1 /g;
print $number;
```

`(\d{2})` means 'two numerical digits'. `(?!$)` means 'as long as the end of the string isn't immediately afterwards', as there's no need for a space after the number.

Comment: `(\d{2})` means 'two numerical digits'.  `(?!$)` means 'as long as the end of the string isn't immediately afterwards', as there's no need for a space after the number.

Comment: `(?!$)` doesn't quite mean that, but `(?!\z)` would. Also, `\K` would be more efficient.

Answer (score 2):

Here's another option:

```
use strict;
use warnings;

my $number = 600000;
my $spacedNum = join ' ', $number =~ /..?/g;
print $spacedNum;
```

Output:

```
60 00 00
```